# C# Invoking Exception TargetSite

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an application that can sometimes throw an exception, most of these are handled but I want the unhandled ones to be recoverable. So I'm trying to invoke the method that caused the exception by using the exception's targetsite like so:

```
        Exception ex = Global.ThrownException;

        MethodBase mB = ex.TargetSite;


        try
        {

            mB.Invoke(mB, null);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
```

I'm doing this to make sure that the exception was a one time error before showing the window to the user again.

The test method (and the exception targetsite) I'm trying to invoke is this:

```
 public void testMethod()
    {
        throw new System.IO.IOException("test");
    }
```

When I run this, an exception is thrown with the message "Object does not match target type" but since testMethod doesn't have any parameters this shouldn't happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to invoke the method on an instance of `MethodBase` (first argument to `.Invoke()`), which clearly doesn't exist. You need to pass in an instance of the object that defines `testMethod()`, since it's not static.

Comment: As @PoweredByOrange said, you need to pass the object that has the method to `Invoke`. Unfortunately, I don't know that there is a good way to get that information from an exception.

Comment: And, to be clear, I think this an interesting question in the *"I wonder if you can actually do that?"* sense. I do not, however, think it's actually a good idea to do in practice. If you have methods that might be retry-able, then you should wrap just *those* methods in some kind of retry logic. A global catch and retry just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I could not agree more with what @MattBurland said.